# PlayFramework2. Using nested classes in router

Tags: java, routes, playframework-2.2

I would like to know is it possible to use nested class as routing destination.

Here is my method:

```
package controllers;
public class MainController {
    public static class NestedController {
        public Result submit() {
            return ok();
        }
    }
}
```

And routing file:

```
GET  /main/nested controllers.MainController$NestedController.submit()
```

But I am getting an error:

```
[error] /home/user/git/play/conf/routes:23: object MainController$NestedController is not a member of package controllers
[error] GET /main/nested controllers.MainController$NestedController.submit()
```

When I set routing file this way:

```
GET  /main/nested controllers.MainController.NestedController.submit()
```

I am getting an error:

```
[error] /home/user/git/play/conf/routes:23: MainController is already defined as object MainController
```

Please help

Comment: Play is very strict regarding the package where a controller is defined and routing. Why would you nest a controller in another one ?

Comment: I don't wanna create to much java classes. I would like to gather them as nested. Is it possible?

Comment: What's the problem with creating a controller for each model ? ^^ That's a best practice to make your code readable and maintanable by you and others.
When you see that your java class has 1000+ lines of codes you'll regret to having put everything in the same file, trust me.

Comment: Anyway, if you still want to do this, show us what your `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/controllers` folder looks like (remove the route throwing the error to compile your code before)

Comment: I tried do this way cause I would like to keep hierarchy in soruces.

Comment: Packages are here for this...